# Easily see Google Analytics data for multiple websites at once

Tags: google-analytics

I have about 50 separate websites.

Instead of switching between Google Analytics property views for 30 minutes, is there a way I can see those propertys' vital stats in a table?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Could possibly do it via Data Studio since you can link a number of data sources to it